# jQuery done() seems to fire before request is sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'm trying to hide an ajax loader after a request is done, but the `done()` callback is firing immediately after the `blur()` event, before the request is made. I made my controller action sleep for 5 seconds to be sure this was the case, and it is. I would think it should fire only after the result comes back from the server, or 5 seconds later. What's going on?

```
  $('#order_billing_post_code').on 'blur', ->
    field = $(this)
    post_code = field.val()
    type = field.data 'address-type'

    if post_code.length is 8
      xhr = $.ajax
        url: "/address_lookups/new"
        data:
          post_code: post_code
        beforeSend: ->
          field.siblings('i.address-ajax-loader').show()
        success: (data) ->
          parse data, type
        dataType: "json"

      xhr.done(
        alert "done"
      )
```

Comment: why not have the `alert "done"` fire on `complete` of the ajax call? take a look at the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Nomad101 because `complete`, `success` etc are "old school" jQuery.

Comment: @Alnitak and the problem is? I mean they still work exactly as they should. Just saying could be a simple and effective solution.

Comment: @Alnitak they're deprecated, no?

Comment: they do indeed still work.  Personally I'd like to see them deprecated and make the promise interface the only supported one.

Comment: @dee the `.complete`, `.success` and `.error` jqXHR members that are synonyms for `.always`, `.done` and `.fail` are deprecated.  The similarly named _options_ to `$.ajax` are not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this syntax (Coffeescript?) but it looks like you're passing the result of calling `alert "done"` immediately to `xhr.done()`, instead of passing a *reference to a function* that calls `alert`.

Try:

```
xhr.done ->
  alert "done"
```

In vanilla JS, it's as if you had written:

```
xhr.done(alert("done"))
```

instead of:

```
xhr.done(function() {
    alert("done");
});
```

The `alert` call happens immediately, and the result is passed to `xhr.done`, which then does nothing useful at all.

Comment: Thank you. That's it. I'll accept as soon as it'll let me. And yes, that's CoffeeScript.